# Identify column if yes

Tags: sql-server

I'm developing a site which will require friend requests and what I want to do is when the logged in user search and in the results some of the people are already his or her friends it should identify but I'm having difficulty doing it.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN resp_email = 'Yes' THEN 'Friend' ELSE 'Send Request' END as Answer
FROM dbo.profile 
INNER JOIN friends On profile.email = MMColParam
WHERE fname LIKE %varsearch%
ORDER BY fname ASC
```

I hope you guys can understand my question.

Comment: What does "rectify" mean?

Comment: Please post the expected result and actual result you are getting with your query.Or atleast the part which you are getting wrong

Comment: for example when @Anand is logged on user and searches for friends and some of the people are already his friends if should write that user2 is already a friend of yours. If user2 is not your friend then send him a request.

Comment: @blay: I can understand the usage.I think the problem may in the join used.Can you post the table structure with the columns used.
Answer from @@codingbiz also tried to use other columns out of your details.so have a look at that too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN ISNULL(resp_email, 'No') = 'No' THEN 'Send Request' ELSE 'Friend' END as Answer
FROM 
   dbo.profile p
   LEFT JOIN friends f On p.email = f.[CurrentUserIDCol]
   AND f.[CurrentUserIDCol] = 'CurrentUserID'
WHERE 
   fname LIKE %varsearch%
ORDER BY fname ASC
```

Hint: Select all profile, do a left join to make sure all profile record are selected.
Check for NULL on the right of the JOIN (friends table). If NULL, it's not a friend yet

Other ways of framing the condition

```
CASE WHEN resp_email IS NOT NULL AND  resp_email  = 'Yes' THEN 'Friend' ELSE 'Send Request' END Answer
```